# Installed python-docx package yet get the ImportError: No module named docx

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-docx

I installed the python-docx package and have verified that it exist using the pip command  Freeze.  When I use that command it shows docx==0.2.0 but when I try to import it in my script I get a ImportError: No module named docx, any ideas whats going on.

Comment: Sounds like it's been installed in a directory that's not in your path.

Comment: how do I find out what directory pip puts the files when installs ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

If you need to find where pip is, you could try the locate command if you're on Linux.

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ulocate.htm

http://linux.die.net/man/1/locate